# Write out the Leutonian numbers that represent the first 12 positive integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

[image]

How could I write out the leutonian numbers that represent the first 12 positive integers ?

I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by trial and error.  If you do this for the first $12$ positive integers you may be able to see a more deterministic way of doing it.

You need to write your number as a sum of numbers chosen from
$$1,\,2,\,3,\,5,\,8,\,13,\,21,\,\ldots$$
in such a way that you never choose two adjacent numbers.  For example you cannot choose both $5$ and $8$.

An example: if you want to make up $16$ then you could start with $13$, then you need another $3$.  You can't take $1$ and $2$ because they are adjacent, but you can simply take $3$ itself.  So you have $16=13+3$, and you write this as $100100$, where the $1$s indicate the numbers $13$ and $3$ which are used, and the $0$s indicate the numbers $8,\,5,\,2,\,1$ which are not used.

See if you can do $1$ to $12$ for yourself.

Comment: In your example, your Leutonian number that represents 16 starts with 0. The definition of Leutonian number is that it starts with 1 from right side.

Comment: I don't think so, look at the example you were given with $25$.

Comment: It says $ s = s_l s_{l-1} ... s_{1} $ is such a string with length $l$.

Comment: That's correct, look at the example you were given with $25$.